# Chrome Headless in Unix returns empty page source

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, unix, google-chrome-headless

Am using Chrome Headless to run my selenium test script in Unix machine(Cent OS).But the same script works perfectly in my local windows machine.

But in Unix machine it returns empty page source like empty html tags.

Have no clue where its error-ed out though am using latest ChromeDriver 2.33, and google chrome version 62.0..

```
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/../chromedriver.exe");

        --chromedriver.exe for windows local machine
        -- chromedriver for unix machine

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
        options.addArguments("--ignore-ssl-errors=true");
        options.addArguments("--ssl-protocol=any");
        options.setHeadless(true);

        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        System.out.println("Timeout invoke ");
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("After invoke ");
        System.out.println("PAGE SOURCE : \n" + driver.getPageSource());
        System.out.println("RUN COMPLETE..");
```

Running the above in Unix machine i get

PAGE SOURCE:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Help me in fixing this
Thanks in advance

Complete StackTrace :

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f) on port 33523 
Only local connections are allowed. org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT
6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) 

Command duration or timeout: 60.41 seconds Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:01:39.354Z' System info: host: 'Windows', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_144' 

Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)  at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)  at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)     at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)  at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
```

Comment: Error is pretty load and clear **`WebDriverException: chrome not reachable`**. You need to cleanup **`Chrome`**

Comment: I ran this test in windows first so i can confirm the script is working..When i remove these options

options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");

the script is working good.So clearly something else is missed out.

Comment: My Answer is as per your Question on `Unix` environment.

Answer (score 2):

To run `Chrome Browser` in `Headless Mode` in `Unix Systems`, add the arguments **`--disable-gpu`** and **`--remote-debugging-port=9222`** :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
options.addArguments("--ignore-ssl-errors=true");
options.addArguments("--ssl-protocol=any");
options.setHeadless(true);
options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
options.addArguments("window-size=1400,600");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
System.out.println("Timeout invoke ");
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println("After invoke ");
System.out.println("PAGE SOURCE : \n" + driver.getPageSource());
System.out.println("RUN COMPLETE..");
```

**Note A**: Avoid passing both the options `addArguments("--headless")` and `setHeadless(true)` together for any single *WebDriver* instance.

**Note B**: Avoid using `addArguments("--disable-gpu");` on Linux/Unix based systems as it is a configuration for Windows based OS.

> Reference : [**`Getting Started with Headless Chrome`**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)

---

### Update

As you are seeing :

```
WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
```

Follow the steps :

- Uninstall `Chrome Browser` through `Revo Uninstaller`
- Run `CCleaner` tool to wipe off all the OS chores.
- Take a `System Restart`
- Install current version of `Chrome Browser`.
- Execute your `Test`

Comment: Added --disable-gpu and tried but no luck..again i was shown the same empty page source

Comment: After adding the debugging port it throws an WebDriverException: chrome not reachable at line driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

Comment: Ran in Windows first and ended up here
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f) on port 33523
Only local connections are allowed.
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
System info: host: 'Windows', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

Comment: Badly this is my workstation and i cannot uninstall chrome as i don't have privilege to do so.

Comment: Updated my Answer with an option. Try out and let me know the Status.

Comment: while these might be useful troubleshooting tips, this doesn't answer the question at all

Comment: @DebanjanB do you realize you suggested users install CCleaner during the time it was backdoored and contained malware that infected 2.3 million PC's with a malicious version?  You should probably leave that suggestion out of your answers.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Especially when adding the proxy which had no valid certificates. Here's what worked for me: (python code)

```
    polipo_proxy = "127.0.0.1:8124"
    proxy = Proxy({
        'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
        'httpProxy': polipo_proxy,
        'ftpProxy' : polipo_proxy,
        'sslProxy' : polipo_proxy,
        'noProxy'  : ''
    })
    capabilities = dict(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
    proxy.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)
    capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True
    capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1280,1000')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("/var/chromedriver/chromedriver"), chrome_options=chrome_options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Comment: `--allow-insecure-localhost` is what I was missing. In non-`--headless` mode it worked with `--ignore-certificate-errors` alone, in `--headless` mode it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

It's problem with ssl certificate , i also had the same issue . for headless chrome following options are not effective  , try to reach other non ssl link . 
chrome options - > --ignore-ssl-errors

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Turns out that in my case the requested page returned a non-successful HTTP status code (4xx in my case), which resulted in the `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` when using `getPageSource`.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue as well but I am able to get the correct html source from requests. Can you tell me how did you resolve it?

Answer (score -1):

On Unix you need a reference to the Chrome Binary file too.

```
options.setChromeBinaryPath("/usr/bin/google-chrome");
```