# How to retrieve html source from the web application WindGuru

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

It's only happen when I use the headless mode.

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    r'C:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\chromedriver.exe',
    chrome_options=options,
)
driver.get('https://www.windguru.cz/3640')
html = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

# Result
# html = <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>
```

What is happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Headless in Unix returns empty page source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47715071/chrome-headless-in-unix-returns-empty-page-source)

Comment: Did you tried it with options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. You simply need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be visible* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.windguru.cz/3640')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#forecasts-page")))
  print(driver.page_source)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class=" no-flash svg no-hiddenscroll no-touchevents hairline no-hires indexeddb" style=""><head>
  <title>Windguru - Argentina - Mar del Plata</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="Robots" content="index,follow" />

  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />

  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="application-name" content="Windguru" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Windguru" />
  <meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#333333" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Windguru" />
  <meta name="msapplication-starturl" content="/" />

  <meta name="theme-color" content="#333333" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="/img/windguru-icon-192x192.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="/img/windguru-icon-192x192.png" />


  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=1" /><meta name="description" content="Windguru weather forecast for Argentina - Mar del Plata. Special wind and weather forecast for windsurfing, kitesurfing and other wind related sports." />
  <meta name="keywords" content="wind forecast, live wind, windsurfing, kitesurfing, kiteboarding, surfing, snowkiting, sailing, paragliding, wave, meteorology, numeric model, wind speed, GFS, WRF, NWW3, ICON, NAM, HRW, WAM, COSMO, GWAM, EWAM, weather stations, wind stations, forecast maps, Argentina - Mar del Plata" />
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="902500120979-b876d301np6vmv1hlcu9kn1rvgg8097o.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="https://www.windguru.net/img/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png" />
  <link rel="icon" href="https://www.windguru.net/img/windguru-icon-196x196.png" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


  <script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase-messaging.js"></script>


  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyDwc6isuJ-h__wL8NbBgRvIYuJ_IoG1ubM",
      authDomain: "windguru-1091.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://windguru-1091.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "windguru-1091",
      storageBucket: "windguru-1091.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "902500120979"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>

  <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-885239-4', 'auto');
    ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);

  ga(function(tracker) {
    window['WGGA_cid'] = tracker.get('clientId');
    window['WGGA_tid'] = tracker.get('trackingId');
  });  
    //ga('send', 'pageview');

  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var WgLang = {"legend":{"SMER":"Wind direction","TMP":"Temperature","WINDSPD":"Wind speed","MWINDSPD":"Modif. wind","APCP":"Rain (mm\/3h)","TCDC":"Cloud cover (%)","HTSGW":"Wave","WAVESMER":"Wave direction","RATING":"Windguru rating","PERPW":"Wave period (s)","APCP1":"Rain (mm\/1h)","GUST":"Wind gusts","SLP":"&lt;span class=\"helpinfhpa\"&gt;*Pressure (hPa)&lt;\/span&gt;","RH":"Humidity (%)","FLHGT":"&lt;span class=\"helpinffl\"&gt;*0\u00b0 isotherm (m)&lt;\/span&gt;","CDC":"Cloud cover (%)&lt;br\/&gt;high \/ mid \/ low","TMPE":"&lt;span class=\"helpinftmp\"&gt;*Temperature &lt;\/span&gt;","WCHILL":"Wind chill","APCPs":"&lt;span class=\"helpinfsnow\"&gt;*Precip. (mm\/3h)&lt;\/span&gt;","APCP1s":"&lt;span class=\"helpinfsnow\"&gt;*Precip. (mm\/1h)&lt;\/span&gt;","WVHGT":"Wind wave","WVPER":"Wind wave per.(s)","WVDIR":"Wind wave dir.","SWELL1":"Swell","SWPER1":"Swell period (s)","SWDIR1":"Swell direction","SWELL2":"2.Swell","SWPER2":"2.Swell period (s)","SWDIR2":"2.Swell dir.","DIRPW":"Wave direction","WAVEDIR":"Wave direction"},"tooltip":{"TMPE":"Temperature at 2 meters above surface adjusted to real altitude of the spot. More info in Help\/FAQ section.","SLP":"Sea level pressure in hPa, values above 1000 hPa are printed &lt;b&gt;as x-1000&lt;\/b&gt;","FLHGT":"Freezing level height in meters","sst":"Sea surface temperature based on satellite data. Valid for oceans and large lakes, more info in help\/FAQ","APCP1s":"Precipitation in milimeters. Bold blue numbers indicate snowfall.","APCPs":"Precipitation in milimeters. Bold blue numbers indicate snowfall."},"dir":["N","NNE","NE","ENE","E","ESE","SE","SSE","S","SSW","SW","WSW","W","WNW","NW","NNW"],"weekday":["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa"],"txt":{"archive":"Archive","tides":"Tides","detail":"Detail \/ Map","link":"Link","timezone":"Timezone","help":"Help","options":"Options","choose_m":"Choose wind modification","loading":"Loading forecast...","delayed":"12 hours delayed forecast. Latest WRF forecasts are only available to Windguru PRO subscribers. &lt;a href='help_index.php?sec=pro'&gt;Click for more info.&lt;\/a&gt;","delayed_short":"12 hours delayed forecast. Latest WRF forecasts are only available to Windguru PRO subscribers.","custom_onlypro":"This forecast is only available to Windguru PRO subscribers","lastupdated":"Last updated","nextexpected":"Next update expected","timeleft":"Time left"},"tab":{"forecast":"Forecast","graph":"&lt;img src=\"\/images\/gricon.png\" width=\"15\" height=\"10\"\/&gt;","2d":"2D","2d_t":"Temperature (0 ... 5000 m)","2d_w":"Wind (0 ... 5000 m)","2d_t_l":"Temperature (alt ... +2000 m)","2d_w_l":"Wind (alt ... +2000 m)","map":"Map","webcams":"Webcams","reports":"Wind reports","accommodation":"Accommodation","schools":"Schools\/Rentals","shops":"Shops","other":"Other...","directory":"Links","fcst_graph":"&lt;img src=\"\/img\/gricon.png\"\/&gt;","more":"&lt;span class=\"butt-txt\"&gt;More&lt;\/span&gt;","statistic":"Statistics","archive":"Archive","alert":"Add alert","share_widget":"Add to your website"},"units":{"kmh":"km\/h","mph":"mph","ms":"m\/s","msd":"m\/s","knots":"knots","bft":"Bft","c":"&amp;deg;C","f":"&amp;deg;F","m":"m","ft":"ft"},"maps":{"windspd":"Wind","t2m":"Temperature","press":"Pressure","tcdc_apcp3":"Rain \/ clouds","tcdc_apcp1":"Rain \/ clouds"},"mapsi":{"windspd":"wind","t2m":"temperature","press":"pressure","tcdc_apcp3":"precipitation","tcdc_apcp1":"precipitation"},"gmap":{"link_f":"Forecast","link_a":"Archive","link_d":"Detail","link_add":"Add to favourites","link_s":"Select"},"spotmenu":{"sel_zeme":"SELECT COUNTRY","sel_spot":"SELECT SPOT","num_spot":"spots","num_reg":"regions","num_zeme":"countries","sel_all":"ALL","qs_hint":"Type spot name (min. 3 characters)"},"langdir":{"dir":"int"}};

  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://beta.windguru.net/js/pak/bs.min.000024.js?WGNOEXP"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://beta.windguru.net/js/pak/wg.min.000112.js?WGNOEXP"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://beta.windguru.net/js/min/WG.Ads.min.000013.js?WGNOEXP"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://beta.windguru.net/css/min/index.min.000048.css?WGNOEXP" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
  WG.cdn = 'https://www.windguru.net';
  WG.forecast_api = 'https://www.windguru.net/int/iapi.php';
  WG.consent_new = 1;
  WG.user = new WG.User();

  WG.camblacklist = [1427387412]
  WG._user_properties = {"id_user":0,"email":null,"username":"","wj":"knots","tj":"c","waj":"m","odh":3,"doh":22,"wrap":40,"fhours":240,"limit1":10.63,"limit2":15.57,"limit3":19.41,"tlimit":10,"vt":"forecast","directory":0,"wrapnew":null,"cellsize":null,"default_set":0,"default_id_spot":53,"consent_timestamp":0,"allow_personal_ads":false,"pro":false,"news_id":18,"news_pulse":1};
  WG.ads.on = true;
  WG.ads.ajax = true;

  </script>
  <script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.windguru.net/js/src/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.windguru.net//js/src/leaflet-mapbox-gl.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.windguru.net/css/src/mapbox-gl.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
  if(navigator.serviceWorker) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.php').catch(function(err) {
      console.error('Unable to register service worker.', err);
    });
  }

  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://beta.windguru.net/js/min/main.min.000070.js?WGNOEXP"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){
       if(WG.isRunningiOSStandalone()) {
       WG.gae('standalone','ios');
       }
       if(WG.isRunningAndroidStandalone()) {
       WG.gae('standalone','android');
       }
  });    
  </script>
  <link rel="preload" href="https://adservice.google.co.in/adsid/integrator.js?domain=www.windguru.cz" as="script" /><script type="text/javascript" src="https://adservice.google.co.in/adsid/integrator.js?domain=www.windguru.cz"></script><link rel="preload" href="https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=www.windguru.cz" as="script" /><script type="text/javascript" src="https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=www.windguru.cz"></script><style>@-webkit-keyframes jBox-animation-zoomOutOpen-open {0% {-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);}100% {-webkit-transform:scale(1);}}.jBox-animation-zoomOutOpen-open {-webkit-animation-duration: 180ms;-webkit-animation-name: jBox-animation-zoomOutOpen-open;}@-webkit-keyframes jBox-animation-zoomOutClose-close {0% {-webkit-transform:scale(1);}100% {-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);}}.jBox-animation-zoomOutClose-close {-webkit-animation-duration: 180ms;-webkit-animation-name: jBox-animation-zoomOutClose-close;}</style><style>@-webkit-keyframes jBox-animation-zoomOutOpen-open {0% {-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);}100% {-webkit-transform:scale(1);}}.jBox-animation-zoomOutOpen-open {-webkit-animation-duration: 180ms;-webkit-animation-name: jBox-animation-zoomOutOpen-open;}@-webkit-keyframes jBox-animation-zoomOutClose-close {0% {-webkit-transform:scale(1);}100% {-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);}}.jBox-animation-zoomOutClose-close {-webkit-animation-duration: 180ms;-webkit-animation-name: jBox-animation-zoomOutClose-close;}</style></head>
  <body id="body" class="with-nested-nicescroll content-bottom-menu pc">
  <div class="nsr" style=""><div class="nsrr"></div></div>    
  <header id="header"> <!-- Horní lišta s logen a vetou -->

  <nav id="nav-windguru"><!-- Navigacní lišta s levým a pravým menu -->

  <a id="menu-button" class="main-mini-menu-icon collapsed"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon light"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_menu"/></svg> </a>
  <a id="menu-button-news" class="menu-news main-mini-menu-icon on pulse" style="" href="javascript:void(0)"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon light"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_new"/></svg></a>

  <div id="div_search_top"><!-- Autocomplete-->
  <a href="/"><div class="logoleft"></div></a> 
  <div class="search_placeholder"> search spots...</div>
  <input class="wg-guide" data-guide-priority="1" data-guide-src="qsearch.php" type="search" tabindex="-1" placeholder="" name="searchspot" id="searchspot" />
  </div>
  <style>
      #sets-menu {
      min-width: 280px !important;
      }
  </style>
  <ul id="wg-main-menu" class="wg-main-menu sm sm-simple sm-simple-collapsible collapsed" data-smartmenus-id="1540549926798273">

    <li class="wg-guide wg-guide-global hide_touch_bm_mobile" data-guide-priority="20" data-guide-src="maps-menu.php"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mainmenu has-submenu" id="showmap" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="sm-1540549926798273-1" aria-expanded="false"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon light"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_map"/></svg><span class="small-tablet-hide collapsed-show"> Maps</span></a>
      <ul id="sm-1540549926798273-1" role="group" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="showmap" aria-expanded="false">
        <li><a data-navig="showMapFcst"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_forecast_map"/></svg><span class=""> Forecasts</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-navig="showMapSpots"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_spot_map"/></svg><span class=""> Spots</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-navig="showMapStations"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_station_map"/></svg><span class=""> Stations</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>  
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mainmenu has-submenu" id="sm-1540549926798273-2" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="sm-1540549926798273-3" aria-expanded="false"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon light"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_menu"/></svg><span class="tablet-hide collapsed-show"> More...</span></a>
      <ul id="sm-1540549926798273-3" role="group" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="sm-1540549926798273-2" aria-expanded="false">
         <li><a href="/top.php" data-ajax="1"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_top_forecast"/></svg> Top forecasts</a></li>
        <li><a href="/archive.php" data-ajax="1" data-addclass="menusize-1"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_archive"/></svg> Archive</a></li>
        <li><a href="/archive-stats.php" data-ajax="1" data-addclass="menusize-1"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_statistic"/></svg> Statistics</a></li>
        <li><a href="/archive-top.php" data-ajax="1" data-addclass="menusize-1"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_top_forecast"/></svg> Top spots</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tides.php" data-ajax="1"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_tide"/></svg> Tides</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://old.windguru.cz"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_left"/></svg> Old Windguru</a></li>
      <li class="min-small-tablet-hide collapsed-hide"><a href="/pro.php" data-ajax="1" data-addclass="hcenter vcenter"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_wg"/></svg><span class=""> Windguru PRO</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="min-small-tablet-hide collapsed-hide"><a href="/apps.php" data-ajax="1" data-addclass="hcenter vcenter" data-showurl="/apps.php"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_phone"/></svg><span class=""> Mobile Apps</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="min-small-tablet-hide collapsed-hide"><a href="/directory.php?utm_source=menu" data-ajax="1" data-addclass="hcenter vcenter" data-showurl="/directory.php"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_center"/></svg><span class=""> Windguru Directory</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="min-small-tablet-hide collapsed-hide"><a onclick="WG.forecastWidget();"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_share"/></svg><span class=""> Forecast widgets</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="min-small-tablet-hide collapsed-hide"><a href="http://stations.windguru.cz"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_station_map"/></svg><span class=""> Windguru Station</span></a>
      </li>
     </ul>  
    </li>
    <li class="small-tablet-hide collapsed-show"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mainmenu has-submenu" id="sm-1540549926798273-4" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="sm-1540549926798273-5" aria-expanded="false"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon light"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_wg"/></svg><span class="tablet-hide collapsed-show"> PROducts</span></a>
      <ul id="sm-1540549926798273-5" role="group" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="sm-1540549926798273-4" aria-expanded="false">
      <li><a href="/pro.php" data-ajax="1" data-addclass="hcenter vcenter"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_wg"/></svg><span class=""> Windguru PRO</span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/apps.php" data-ajax="1" data-addclass="hcenter vcenter"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_phone"/></svg><span class=""> Mobile Apps</span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/directory.php?utm_source=menu" data-ajax="1" data-addclass="hcenter vcenter" data-showurl="/directory.php"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_center"/></svg><span class=""> Windguru Directory</span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a onclick="WG.forecastWidget();"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_share"/></svg><span class=""> Forecast widgets</span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://stations.windguru.cz"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_station_map"/></svg><span class=""> Windguru Station</span></a>
      </li>
      </ul>  
    </li>
    <li class="collapsed-show"><a class="mainmenu has-submenu" id="sm-1540549926798273-6" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="sm-1540549926798273-7" aria-expanded="false"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon light"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_help"/></svg><span class="small-screen-hide collapsed-show"> Help</span></a>
      <ul id="sm-1540549926798273-7" role="group" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="sm-1540549926798273-6" aria-expanded="false">
         <li><a href="/news.php" data-ajax="1" data-addclass="hcenter vcenter"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_new"/></svg> News</a></li>
      <li><a class="click-menu-hide" data-navig="showGuide"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_help"/></svg> Quick guide</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/help.php" data-ajax="1" data-addclass="hcenter vcenter"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_model_selection"/></svg><span class=""> Help section</span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="click-menu-hide" data-navig="keyboardShortcuts"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_more_02"/></svg><span class=""> Keyboard shortcuts</span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/index.php?s=76&amp;intro=1"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_info"/></svg><span class=""> New site intro</span></a>
      </li>
      </ul>       
    </li>
  </ul>

  <a href="/" class="medium-screen-hide"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="logoright" src=""/></a>  

  <ul id="wg-main-menu2" class="wg-main-menu sm sm-simple sm-simple-collapsible collapsed" style="float: right;" data-smartmenus-id="1540549926807642">
    <li class="menu-news on pulse" id="menu-button-news2"><a class="mainmenu" href="javascript:void(0)"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon light"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_new"/></svg><span class="small-screen-hide collapsed-show"> News</span></a></li>

    <li><a class="mainmenu modal-form" id="wg-options" data-q="set_options" data-title="Options" href="/forms/options.php"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon light"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_options"/></svg><span class="big-tablet-hide collapsed-show"> Options</span></a></li>
    <li class="wg-guide wg-guide-global" data-guide-priority="2" data-guide-src="login.php">
      <a href="javascript:WG.user.loginWindow();" class="mainmenu" id="wg_login_link"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon light"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_account"/></svg><span class="tablet-hide collapsed-show"> Login</span></a>
    </li>  
    <li class="small-mobile-hide collapsed-show"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mainmenu has-submenu" id="sm-1540549926807642-1" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="sm-1540549926807642-2" aria-expanded="false"><img class="langflag w480-hide collapsed-show" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/en.png" /><span class="small-mobile-hide collapsed-show">en</span></a>
      <ul id="sm-1540549926807642-2" role="group" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="sm-1540549926807642-1" aria-expanded="false"><li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=baq"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/baq.png" alt="baq" />Basque</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=bg"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/bg.png" alt="bg" />Bulgarian</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=cat"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/cat.png" alt="cat" />Catalan</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=cz"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/cz.png" alt="cz" />Czech</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=dk"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/dk.png" alt="dk" />Danish</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=nl"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/nl.png" alt="nl" />Dutch</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=en"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/en.png" alt="en" />English</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=ee"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/ee.png" alt="ee" />Estonian</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=fi"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/fi.png" alt="fi" />Finnish</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=fr"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/fr.png" alt="fr" />French</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=gl"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/gl.png" alt="gl" />Galician</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=de"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/de.png" alt="de" />German</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=hu"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/hu.png" alt="hu" />Hungarian</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=it"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/it.png" alt="it" />Italian</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=lv"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/lv.png" alt="lv" />Latvian</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=lt"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/lt.png" alt="lt" />Lithuanian</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=pl"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/pl.png" alt="pl" />Polish</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=pt"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/pt.png" alt="pt" />Portuguese</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=ro"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/ro.png" alt="ro" />Romanian</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=ru"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/ru.png" alt="ru" />Russian</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=es"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/es.png" alt="es" />Spanish</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=se"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/se.png" alt="se" />Swedish</a></li>
  <li><a href="/switchlang.php?lang=tr"><img class="langflag" src="https://www.windguru.net/img/flags/tr.png" alt="tr" />Turkish</a></li>
  </ul>  
    </li>  
  </ul>

  </nav>

  </header>

  <div id="minimap" class=""></div>
  <div id="news-div" class=""></div>

  <div id="forecasts-page" class="subsection content">
      <div id="warning-content"></div>
      <div id="forecasts-page-content"></div><div class="end"></div><div id="forecasts-page-fmenu"></div>
      <div id="bottom-menu-forecasts" class="forecasts-page-include menu fixed bottom higher dark subsection hide">
      <a class="menu-button" onclick="WGA.goSearch();"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon light"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_search"/></svg><span class=""> Search</span></a>
      <a class="menu-button showfavo"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon light"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_favourite"/></svg><span class=""> Favourites</span></a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="menu-button" data-navig="showMapFcst" id="showmap"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon light"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_map"/></svg><span class="small-tablet-hide collapsed-show"> Maps</span></a>
      <a class="menu-button" onclick="WGA.options();"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon light"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_options"/></svg><span class="big-tablet-hide collapsed-show"> Options</span></a>    </div>     
  </div>    

  <div id="main-page" class="subsection content hide">
      <div id="main-page-content"></div>
      <div id="bottom-menu-main" class="main-page-include menu fixed bottom higher dark subsection hide">
      <a class="menu-button" onclick="WGA.showHome();"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon light"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_accommodation"/></svg><span class=""> Home </span></a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="menu-button" data-navig="showMapFcst" id="showmap"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon light"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_map"/></svg><span class="small-tablet-hide collapsed-show"> Maps</span></a>
      <a class="menu-button" onclick="WGA.options();"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon light"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ico_options"/></svg><span class="big-tablet-hide collapsed-show"> Options</span></a>    </div>     
  </div>
  ```