# Python Selenium finding element after driver.get() unreliable—sometimes works others doesn't

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am having an issue where after calling `get()`, the code sometimes works, other times it doesn't.  No search results have this issue.  Why would it work sometimes, other times it won't.  Simple code to reproduce:

```
def get_url(search):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('-headless')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://genius.com/')
    print('go')
    elem = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'application')
    print(elem)
    driver.quit()
```

I've been troubleshooting for hours, so it's an excerpt at it's simplest, with some debugging.  It could work twice in a row, then not work twice or three times.  Rinse and repeat.  Any ideas?

EDIT:
Also, I have tried WebDriverWait as well.  Same thing happens.  Sometimes it succeeds, other times it doesn't.  When it doesn't succeed, it seems to get stuck at `get()`.  After 1 or 2 mins, it errors out and the script closes.  Odd.

Comment: try/catch the driver.get() call and include any exceptions you receive.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code trials:

```
elem = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'application')
```

The [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) identifies the element:

```
<div id="application">...</div>
```

which is more or less the entire webpage

[image: webpage]

In realtime scenarios there would be seldom any usecase where where you would like to identify the enire application as a WebElement. Generally, [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70386067/7429447) are much smaller elements for e.g. an `<input>`, a `<span>`, a `<div>` etc.

---

### This usecase

To print the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) entire application a better approach would be to print the [***page_source***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53006894/7429447) as follows:

```
print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: Yeah, that was just troubleshooting code to get it to work.  For me, the driver would sometimes find the element, sometimes not.  Repeatedly.  I just stepped back, looked at ToS, and said "no".  The site's ToS does not allow scraping, and I can't get the scraper to work anyway, so I just dropped the project.  Thanks though.

Comment: Doesn't this answer explains why the driver would sometimes find the element, sometimes not?

Comment: I don't know, TBH.  I was having trouble with elements that were not the root element as well—same thing would happen.  I just posted mid-troubleshooting.  I wasn't actually trying to get the root element in my real project.  It was a `<div class...`.  I'll be stark naked honest: I don't really understand the answer.